# Postgres transaction seems to take AccessExclusiveLock for no reason

Tags: postgresql, transactions, locking

After a lot of googling, I figured I'd ask this question. I have a piece of code which does the following against a postgres (9.2) database :

1. Start transaction
2. drop indexes (5 indexes) on the table
3. insert a million rows into the table
4. Re-create the indexes
5. commit the transaction.

My reading of postgres tells me that I should be able to do that and still allow other users to select from the table (actually even use the existing indexes as they are not yet dropped for them) while this operation is ongoing.

What I'm actually finding is that all other queries on the table (they are *all* select queries) are stuck. Upon looking the pg_locks and pg_stat_activity table, i found that my transaction has created an AccessExclusiveLock on the table preventing other queries from running. Once this transaction finishes, all other queries execute just fine.

So, my question is - why is a create index/insert data creating an exclusive lock on the table? Should'nt it be using a less intrusive lock (like a SHARE lock for example)?

I'm basing this upon my reading of the offical documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/explicit-locking.html) - so I don't get flamed asking to RTFM from anybody :)

Thanks,
Jalpesh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've also wanted this, but you can't do it.

It is not the create index nor the insert that is taking the AccessExclusive lock on the table, it is the drop index which is doing so.

The documentation does not provide an exhaustive list of every situation that acquires every type of lock--it only provides illustrative examples (but perhaps this example should be included in it).

I believe there are many parts of the code which assume that indices cannot disappear while an AccessShare lock on the table is held.  So dropping an index needs to conflict with that.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to be able to query your table during bulk insert and speed up this bulk insert by not maintaining indexes during inserting.

I think you could be able to achieve this using this procedure:

```
begin;    

maxid = select max(id) from table_name;    

create index table_name_id_tmp_idx where id<=maxid;    

drop index table_name_id_idx;    

commit;    

begin;    

do_bulk_insert();    

create index table_name_id_idx on table_name(id);    

drop index table_name_id_tmp_idx;    

commit;
```

It wouldn't be possible for every index, as you need this `where` predicate for partial index that would return `true` for existing rows and `false` for inserted. But serial columns, timestamps etc. could work.

Comment: While useful for `id = X` types of queries, with X hard coded, that partial index would not be for generic `id = ?`, or joins for that matter, unless the code is also rewritten to something like `where id = ? and id < :maxid`.

Comment: @Denis: It depends on a framework or library used. AFAIK most libraries (PHP PDO, Python psycopg etc., but I'm not sure about Java JDBC) do not use prepared queries, as provided by Postgres. Most encourage using parametrized queries, but substitute variables internally - Postgres server only sees ordinary queries, which would work.

Comment: Best I'm aware, PDO actually defaults to real prepared statements unless you explicitly request emulated prepares. No idea about the other ones you mention, but I'd lean towards thinking the ruby libraries all use real prepared statements as well. Still a good answer, mind you (+1, too), but with caveats depending on what OP or future users are using.

Comment: @Denis: I'm afarid that's not quite right - both mysql and pgsql PDO drivers use emulated prepares by default. You can check this easily - there'll be no error when you `prepare('garbage')`, but only after you `execute()` it.